# ZeroMQ synchronized PUB-SUB: Subscriber hangs with synchronization but works normally otherwise

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using ZeroMQ to establish a publisher/subscriber communication model.
The publisher creates a zmq context and then opens a socket with the PUB
communication pattern. It then binds to a port, as the TCP transport protocol is used. For the synchronization a separate socket is opened with the REP communication pattern that binds in a different path. Unless a synchronization request in `msg = syncservice.recv()` is received, the program cannot continue. It then does some rudimentary work and starts over again. Here's the code for the publisher:

```
import pickle, zmq, random, string

# Wait for 1 subscriber
SUBSCRIBERS_EXPECTED = 1

def randomword(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

while True:
    try:
        arguments = {}
        data = {}
        context = zmq.Context()

        # Socket to talk to clients
        publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        # set SNDHWM, in case of slow subscribers
        publisher.sndhwm = 1100000
        publisher.bind('tcp://*:5561')

        # Socket to receive signals
        syncservice = context.socket(zmq.REP)
        syncservice.bind('tcp://*:5562')

        # Get synchronization from subscribers
        subscribers = 0
        while subscribers < SUBSCRIBERS_EXPECTED:
            # wait for synchronization request
            msg = syncservice.recv()
            # send synchronization reply
            syncservice.send(b'')
            subscribers += 1

        for n in range(1000):
            for i in range(random.randrange(1, 6)):
                arguments[i] = randomword(random.randrange(2, 10))

            data['func_name_' + str(n)] = randomword(8)
            data['arguments_' + str(n)] = arguments

        data_string = pickle.dumps(data)
        publisher.send(data_string)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupt received, stopping...")
        break
```

The subscriber functions pretty much the same way the publisher does, albeit
from a subscriber perspective. Here's the code for the subscriber:

```
import pickle, zmq, pprint, time

context = zmq.Context()

# Connect the subscriber socket
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect('tcp://localhost:5561')
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')

time.sleep(1)

# Synchronize with publisher
syncclient = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
syncclient.connect('tcp://localhost:5562')

# Initialize poll set
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(syncclient, zmq.POLLIN)
poller.register(subscriber, zmq.POLLIN)

# send a synchronization request
syncclient.send(b'')

while True:
    try:
        socks = dict(poller.poll())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupt received, stopping...")
        break

    # wait for synchronization reply
    if syncclient in socks:
        syncclient.recv()
        print('Sync')

    if subscriber in socks:
        msg = subscriber.recv()
        data = pickle.loads(msg)
        pprint.pprint(data)
        syncclient.send(b'')
```

The desired result would be for the publisher to publish endlessly, while the
subscriber continually receives and prints everything. If I remove the
synchronization part, everything runs as expected. If I keep the synchronization
part the subscriber hangs after a number of transmissions. The interesting thing
is that if I send a keyboard interrupt (Ctrl-C) and then restart the subscriber,
it will receive a couple of transmissions again and hang again and so on and so
forth.

I have tried different high-watermark settings, but it didn't make any difference. I have tried closing the sockets and terminating the context after every loop. I've tested if the overhead from printing or pickling (serializing) was too much, but it wasn't it either. I have also modified the [suicidal snail example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:suisnail) to work in this case, but the subscriber didn't die. What am I missing? (Python 3 is used for every example)

Comment: Thank you. Have you found a solution to your problem?